# Is this code a good candidate for a lambda function?

Tags: visual-c++, lambda, mfc

I have 27 of these in my function:

```
auto i = m_lbLanguage.AddString(_T("Afrikaans (Afrikaans)"));
m_lbLanguage.SetItemData(i, static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(LanguageMSA::Afrikaans));

i = m_lbLanguage.AddString(_T("Cebuano (Cebuano)"));
m_lbLanguage.SetItemData(i, static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(LanguageMSA::Cebuano));

i = m_lbLanguage.AddString(_T("汉语（简化字）Chinese (Simplified)"));
m_lbLanguage.SetItemData(i, static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(LanguageMSA::ChineseSimplified));
```

Is this type of code a good candidate to use a lambda function? I know I can add a regular function, eg:

```
void Cxxx::AddLanguageToLB(CString strLanguage, LanguageMSA eLanguage)
{
    auto i = m_lbLanguage.AddString(strLanguage);
    m_lbLanguage.SetItemData(i, static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(eLanguage);
}
```

And the use:

```
AddLanguageToLB(_T("汉语（简化字）Chinese (Simplified)"), LanguageMSA::ChineseSimplified);
```

Comment: unrelated: "simplified" Chinese is usually written 简体字 whereas here you've got 简化字

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of code is a good candidate for a table-driven implementation. Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
struct {
  LPCTSTR name;
  LanguageMSA code;
} languages[] = {
  {_T("Afrikaans (Afrikaans)"), LanguageMSA::Afrikaans},
  {_T("Cebuano (Cebuano)"), LanguageMSA::Cebuano},
  // ...
};

for (auto& lang : languages) {
  auto i = m_lbLanguage.AddString(lang.name);
  m_lbLanguage.SetItemData(i, static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(lang.code));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and sample code.